# Print the values of the shortest path from any element to a given element in the matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Input data: number of rows, number of columns, and the point's coordinates
the named position will  be given the value 0.
note: indexing starts from 1 (bad practice, I know, but that's the requirement)
i.e: for this input 4 5 1 1
this matrix will be generated:
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7

I don't want the code, but if someone could give me a hint or something to help, it would be greatly appreciated!! If code is easier than explaining a way to solve it, then please don't hesitate to post it.(C++)
Edit: I got a solution, how could I make this faster?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int v[501][501], i, j, m, n, o, p;
    cin >> m >> n >> o >> p;
    for (i = o; i >= 1; i--)
            v[i][p] = o - i;
    for(i = o;i <= m; i++)
        v[i][p] = i - o;
    for(i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            if(j < p)
                v[i][j] = -j + p + v[i][p];
            else if(j > p)
                v[i][j] = j - p + v[i][p];            
        }
    for(i = 1 ; i <= m; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps https://https://math.stackexchange.com/ is better for this? It has nothing to do with c++ and no other language either as I can see.

Comment: I have to implement it in C++. It is very easy to do it on paper, no math is needed for this except counting and simple logic.

Comment: Ok, then make a [mcve].

Comment: I suppose you might be right, I may have asked the question on a wrong forum.  At the moment of posting this I thought that this community knows to solve problems way harder than this one and someone could explain an algorithm to solve it, I would then post the code for review and that would be it.. I didn't think about posting  on math.stackexchange.com because if you do the problem on paper, it's really easy, a 2nd grader could do it if you explained them what the rule is, yet I can't think of an explanation for the computer to do this without writing 40-60lines of code.

Comment: If it's really easy, just make a first naive implementation of it following the same rules you would follow with pen and paper. When that is done, see if it can be improved. if you get stuck on that first naive implementation, ask a specific question about the problem you're facing.

Comment: alright, thank you for being so understanding!

Comment: @TedLyngmo, what do you think? This is my first post, I read through the rules on stackoverflow and I wish that my skills will become better over time.

Comment: Brilliant - but you actually solved the problem, so now the question is better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That's where working code goes to get better. :-)

Comment: You are welcome! ... and I found your [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239854/create-a-matrix-with-all-elements-having-the-value-of-the-shortest-path-to-a-giv) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to draw the answer for a few examples and you will see a pattern that you can mimic.

For example:

5 5 3 3

4 3 2 3 4

3 2 1 2 3

2 1 0 1 2

3 2 1 2 3

4 3 2 3 4

By the way this is a standard question to solve with BFS.

Comment: I think of the matrix as an XY graph, origin in the given point. column of given point is Y axis and the row is the X axis. Elements on X and Y are the distance of cells to the origin. Now that i have the elements on the 2 axis, I start form element [1][1], see how far it is from the element already completed on the axis and just sum the number of cells needed to reach that element with the number from the already existing cell.. However, I feel like this algorithm would be too long for this task, isn't there a better way to do it? I read a little about BFS but I did not understand it..